# Check that a string only contains A-Z, a-z and - (dash) characters using preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I've tried:

```
print_r(preg_match("[A-Za-z\\-]", $str));
```

And I'm getting false. I'm not very good at regex but it seems to work on http://regexpal.com/

Am I missing something here?

EDIT:
e.g. `$str = zREBsZtyvw`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Description

This expression will ensure you have 1 or more uppercase, lower case, or hypens in the the string with no whitespace

`^[A-Za-z\\-]{1,}$`

[image]

## Match Pattern Explanation:

`(^[A-Za-z\\-]{1,}$)`

matches as follows:

`(` group

`^`  the beginning of the string

`[A-Za-z\\-]{1,}`   any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z', '\', '-' (at least 1 times (matching the  most amount possible))

`$`  before an optional \n, and the end of the string

`)` end of grouping

## PHP Code Example:

```
<?php
$sourcestring="zREBsZtyvw";
preg_match_all('/^[A-Za-z\\-]{1,}$/i',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => zREBsZtyvw
        )

)
```

Comment: I had a look at your profile. Your regex answers are very thorough. Thanks for covering pretty much head to toe on the pattern matches, I appreciate the effort.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words. I really like taking on these challenges and making them easy to understand  :)

Comment: Please use `+` instead of `{1,}`.

Comment: `+` and `{1,}` are functionally identical, however `{1,}` is easier to find and modify if you later decide you'd like to match at least 2 of something, or at most X of something.

Comment: what application did you use to generate the graph ?

Answer (score 3):

Jerry and Yomy each identified half the problem. Here's the whole solution:

```
print_r(preg_match("/^[A-Za-z\\-]*$/", $str));
```

`preg_match` requires you to have matching delimiters at the beginning and end of the regexp. And you need to anchor the regexp so that it will check the whole string, not just look for a match anywhere in the strong. And you need to use the `*` wildcard to match any number of characters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the anchors (`^` and `$`) to specify that you string *starts* and *ends* with only those characters:

```
print_r(preg_match("/^[A-Za-z\\-]$/", $str));
                     ^           ^
```

Comment: I'm getting this warning: `Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found`

Comment: @meiryo ahh, I forgot that preg_match() needs slashes before and after the regex. I'm not familiar with it that much. See edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually - you're missing escape characters (/) on beginning and end of your pattern,
and you've used [] which matches only one character in group

Best pattern would be to use repetition and start/end anchors

"/^[a-zA-Z-]*$/"

print_r(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-]*$/", $str));

Comment: This works however it's still taking 0-9 and return true.

Comment: Sorry - my browser just tricked me into sending uncompleted, so I edited... This should work. - Barmar also sent similar thing in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a double backslash.. but you also need delimiters at the start and end of the regex (/'s)

```
print_r(preg_match("/^[A-Za-z\-]+$/", $str));
```

I've used the + instead of * as you'd want to match 1 or more. With a *, an empty string would match.